# Convert rows to columns in mysql v3

Tags: mysql, row

From this code is it possible that for locationid 5,6,7,8 it will be on the 2nd row instead of it continuing?

```
SELECT
    MAX(case when locationid = '1' then floatvalue end) Flow,
    MAX(case when locationid = '2' then floatvalue end) Level,
    MAX(case when locationid = '3' then floatvalue end) Pressure,
    MAX(case when locationid = '4' then floatvalue end) MR,  
    MAX(case when locationid = '5' then floatvalue end) Flow,
    MAX(case when locationid = '6' then floatvalue end) Level,
    MAX(case when locationid = '7' then floatvalue end) Pressure,
    MAX(case when locationid = '8' then floatvalue end) MR
FROM table
```

So instead of this:

```
Flow | Level | Pressure | MR | Flow | Level | Pressure | MR  |
10   |  20   |   30     | 40 | 100  |  200  |   300    | 400 |
```

it will like this:

```
Flow | Level | Pressure | MR  |
 10  |  20   |   30     | 40  |
 100 |  200  |   300    | 400 |
```

Comment: no. you cannot write something in sql that will produce two records from a single one. if you want two rows displayed, then put that logic into the client software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 1 THEN floatvalue END) Flow,
       MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 2 THEN floatvalue END) Level,
       MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 3 THEN floatvalue END) Pressure,
       MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 4 THEN floatvalue END) MR
  FROM table1
 WHERE locationid IN(1, 2, 3, 4)
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 5 THEN floatvalue END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 6 THEN floatvalue END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 7 THEN floatvalue END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN locationid = 8 THEN floatvalue END)
  FROM table1
 WHERE locationid IN(5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2a53/1)** demo

Comment: @hearmeroar Sorry, I don't quite understand what do you mean by *does union all have a limit?*. Can you elaborate a bit what you want to achieve?

Comment: i mean the select statement that i can using union all, is there a limit? like only until 5 statements can be used on union all

Comment: @hearmeroar No there is no specific limit on that.